# Spark classpath conflict

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am using spark version `2.1.0`, I use

```
./bin/spark-submit --master spark://some_master_host_name:7077 \
--class com.foo.bar.SomeApp \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--conf spark.jars=libraries/avro-1.8.2.jar \
--jars libraries/avro-1.8.2.jar \
--conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=avro-1.8.2.jar \
--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=avro-1.8.2.jar \
--conf spark.files.fetchTimeout=600s \
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/some_file_name.hprof" \
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:+PrintReferenceGC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/some_file_name.hprof" \
/some/where/on/disk/FOO-assembly.jar
```

to submit spark application to the cluster. On application side I have following debug logging enabled to inspect classpath

```
private static void printSystemClasspath() {
    System.err.println("-------System Classpath--------------");
    String[] entries = System.getProperty("java.class.path").split("\\:");
    for (String entry : entries) {
        System.err.println(entry + " - " + new File(entry).exists());
    }
    System.err.println("-------------------------------------");
}

private static void printCurrentThreadClassloaderClasspath() {
    System.err.println("-------Current Thread Classpath--------------");
    ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader) cl).getURLs();
    for (URL url : urls) {
        System.err.println(url.getFile());
    }
    System.err.println("-------------------------------------");
}
```

Problem : I am trying to override spark's supplied avro version and supply 1.8.2 at runtime.

I have proper version of avro classes packaged inside `FOO-assembly.jar` but when I use `spark.driver.userClassPathFirst` or `spark.executor.userClassPathFirst` I run into some other conflicts. I want to be able to just override avro library at runtime to upgraded version.

I receive first entry in System classpath as `avro-1.8.2.jar` but the file isn't present on the file system (code evaluates to `false`)

How can I override the classpath in this situation ?

Comment: There is no way to update a specific dependency. At that Spark (really just Java) cares about is the classpath property ordering, which is either everything in your app first, or not.

Comment: AFAIK, the alternative is to replace the avro jar in the Spark cluster yourself and not bundle it with your app

Comment: replacing it in spark cluster will be too much of overhead and it will impact across different spark apps. I wanted to see if there is a way to prioritize it in classpath without rewriting classloader

Comment: In my opinion, replacing it on the cluster could be dangerous if it's not a version compatible with spark. I've solved similar problems by bundling a shaded version of conflicting libraries.

Comment: @Travis did you mean rewrite `org.apache.avro.*` classes to something like `foo.org.apache.avro.*` and pack it in fat jar and update references in source to refer to this ?

Comment: Yes. I use `maven`, and a plugin called `maven-shade-plugin`, which updates code references on the fly during the `package` stage. It's important to *exclude* any of the spark dependencies that already exist in the cluster, or you'll have the same problem with your fat jar's spark copy referencing the shaded classes.

Comment: Thanks @Travis - In my case the usage of avro is from a binary itself transitively. I don't think this will help in this particular case. I have been able to work around it by using `spark.[driver,executor].userClassPathFirst`

Comment: @user3833308 can you please let me know how did you achieved this? I'm facing the similar issue wrt commons-io